# Javascript condition not working as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a JS code which works fine when

```
checkQueryString != "M"
```

but When the value becomes `checkQueryString == "M"` it doesn't goes inside the loop

Here is my code.

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientAdd(record) {
        var checkQueryString = '<%= Request.QueryString["Mode"] %>';    
        if (checkQueryString != "M") {
            if ($('input:checked').length > 0) {

                document.getElementById("GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_txtExpRefNo").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_txtExpRefDt").disabled = true;

                document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').value = "";
                var last_value = 0;
                var last_text;

                var checkboxlist = document.getElementById('ddlStatus');
                var checkOptions =   checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('input');
                var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('label');

                for (i = 0; i < checkOptions.length; i++) {
                    if (checkOptions[i].checked == true) {
                        last_text = listSelected[i].innerText;
                        last_value =  checkOptions[i].value;
                        document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').innerHTML = "";
                        var ObjPriOptionExp = document.createElement("OPTION");
                        ObjPriOptionExp.text = last_text;                    
                        ObjPriOptionExp.value = last_value;
                        document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').add(ObjPriOptionExp);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(checkQueryString == "M")
            {
               alert('Value is M now'); 
            }
            else {
                alert('Kindly select the stage');
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is, why it doesn't goes inside `if` when it matches to `M`

Comment: You are first checking if it doesn't match `M`, and inside that statement you are checking if it's matching `M`. That's like checking `if (a == true) { if (a == false){ // will never be executed } }`

Comment: it does not go inside if because it is never equals to M. You are already entering the first if block when checkQueryString != 'M'

Comment: Just want to ask you want to get inside the loop if the value of  `checkQueryString` is M?. Then why use `if (checkQueryString != "M")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
if (checkQueryString == "M") {
    alert('Value is M now');
} else {
    alert('Kindly select the stage');
}
```

Has inside `if (checkQueryString == "M")`

So try this

```
function GridExpInfo_ClientAdd(record) {
    var checkQueryString = '<%= Request.QueryString["Mode"] %>';
    if (checkQueryString != "M") {
        if ($('input:checked').length > 0) {

            document.getElementById("GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_txtExpRefNo").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_txtExpRefDt").disabled = true;

            document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').value = "";
            var last_value = 0;
            var last_text;

            var checkboxlist = document.getElementById('ddlStatus');
            var checkOptions = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('input');
            var listSelected = checkboxlist.getElementsByTagName('label');

            for (i = 0; i < checkOptions.length; i++) {
                if (checkOptions[i].checked == true) {
                    last_text = listSelected[i].innerText;
                    last_value = checkOptions[i].value;
                    document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').innerHTML = "";
                    var ObjPriOptionExp = document.createElement("OPTION");
                    ObjPriOptionExp.text = last_text;
                    ObjPriOptionExp.value = last_value;
                    document.getElementById('GridExpInfo_tplRowEdit3_ctl00_ddlStageType').add(ObjPriOptionExp);
                }
            }
        }

    } else if (checkQueryString == "M") {
        alert('Value is M now');
    } else {
        alert('Kindly select the stage');
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: not working, my simple `else` alert is not working when i dont select any value

Comment: what is output of `console.log(checkQueryString )`